# How to hide information_schema database from phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I am able to hide the database from writing this line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema';
```

in config.inc.php file pf phpmyadmin.

It is possible to access content of this database through url like http://www.test.com/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=information_schema&token=3ba37ae1e41f6a10e4afc7c69b934bba

How is it possible to remove complete access of information_schema database ?

Answer (score 40):

Follow these steps:

1. Open phpMyAdmin, authenticate yourself, if required
2. Go to *Settings > Features > Databases*
3. Put list of databases that you want to hide into *Hide databases* field, separating each entry with a pipe (`|`), i.e.: `information_schema|performance_schema|mysql|phpmyadmin`
4. Click *Apply* button

As per *KeshV*'s comments below, depending on your operating system (Linux, Windows etc.) and environment configuration you may need to have *config.inc.php* file writable in order to have above changes persistent between server or browser restarts.

However, on some configurations and in certain *phpMyAdmin* versions the above settings are stored directly in cookie and are preserved even though noting is added to *config.inc.php* file.

Comment: It won't work if the config.inc.php is not writable, so this won't survive on logout

Answer (score 32):

You can even hide multiple DBs using pipe separator

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema|performance_schema|mysql';
```

Comment: This is the perfect answer !!

Comment: for those who don't know where to do that, go to config.inc.php file and put this line at the end and refresh phpmyadmin page to see the changes.

Answer (score 5):

In case you also want to restrict users from accessing the information_schema from a url like you posted and you are not satisfied with `hide_db` configuration directive then you may add the following line in config.inc.php file of phpmyadmin.

```
if($_GET['db'] == 'information_schema')exit;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd write this comment on the highest upvoted answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

When specifying multiple databases, keep in mind it operates under RegEx rules (as the help states). So while it may be unlikely, putting "information_schema|performance_schema|mysql" will also hide any DB's that contain these strings.

Instead, put "^information_schema|performance_schema|mysql$". In regular expressions, ^ denotes the beginning of the string, and $ denotes the end.

This means you can also hide databases by partial string. While you should always control database access by MySQL user permissions, you can hide groups of DB's using partial matching. For example if you didn't want all your test databases visible, you could put "^test_" in the hidden databases field and it will hide all databases that start with test_. EG test_123, test_456.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `config.inc.php` file in the `phpymyadmin` folder:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = 'information_schema|performance_schema|mysql|phpmyadmin|test';
```